# How to correct url path

Tags: 7

I am using a key to connect with it's *node nid* but when I click on *Next* it gives path `/node/node/256` instead of `node/256`. Here is my code:

```
$key = array_search($nid , $nids);
print $key;
$next = ($key + '1');
$previous = ($key - 1);
$total=count($nids);
$next_link =    "<a href='node/$nids[$next]'>Next</a>";
$previous_link = "<a href='node/$nids[$previous]'>Previous</a>";
```

*$nids* is an array. How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to construct URLs in Drupal.

```php
$next_link = l('Next', 'node/' . $nids[$next]);
$previous_link = l('Previous', 'node/' . $nids[$previous]);
```

Comment: thanx anil they show in url their nid if we want to show its alias then what i do?

Comment: @Adi If a path has an alias, `l()` will use the alias automatically

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you wanted just the alias, but not the whole link then you could use [drupal_get_path_alias](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7):

```
$alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$nid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct next and prev node url by content type

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $type = $node->type;

  $prev = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition('n.status', 1, '=')
    ->condition('n.type', $type, '=')
    ->condition('n.created', $node->created, '<')
    ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC')
    ->range(0, 1)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchField();

  $next = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition('n.status', 1, '=')
    ->condition('n.type', $type, '=')
    ->condition('n.created', $node->created, '>')
    ->orderBy('n.created', 'ASC')
    ->range(0, 1)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchField();

  if ($prev) {
    $prev_link = l('Previous', 'node/' . $prev);

  }
  if ($next) {
    $next_link = l('Next', 'node/' . $next);
  }

}
```